# How to give output string in threadstart?

Tags: c#

I got this error

> Method name expected.

for this code:

```
thSystem[index] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cls.StartProcess(out string)));
```

How to do the overload for output value?

I want to take out string from StartProcess.

Below is my code:

//declare function

```
       clsCallProcess cls = new clsCallProcess(index, url, name, timer);
       thSystem[index] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(cls.StartProcess(out string)));
       thSystem[index].Start();
```

//function

```
      public class clsCallProcess
    {
        private int mindex;
        private string murl;
        private string mname;
        private int mtimer;
        bool IsRunning = true;

        // The constructor obtains the state information.
        public clsCallProcess(int index, string url, string name, int timer)
        {
            mindex = index;
            murl = url;
            mname = name;
            mtimer = timer;
        }

        public void StartProcess(out string result)
        {
            //First run checking
            result = "Connection Success";
            while (IsRunning)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(mtimer);
                IsRunning = false;

                try
                {
                    //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("Process Start", mname);
                    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                    string html = Utility.RequestWebpage(murl, string.Empty, true);
                    TimeSpan minisecond = DateTime.Now - start;

                    FileManager.WriteActivityLog("time:" + minisecond.Milliseconds.ToString() + ",html length:" + html.Length.ToString(), mname);
                    //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("html:" + html, mname);
                    //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("Process End", mname);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionManager.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message, true, mname);
                    result = ex.Message;
                }
                IsRunning = true;
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you run something in a loop forever (right now your thread loop will never end as `IsRunning` will always be true) to check for some webpage periodically.

One way to get the periodic results back is an event handler which gets raised every time you have made a connection attempt. It could look like this:

```
public class PageWatcher
{
    private int mindex;
    private string murl;
    private string mname;
    private int mtimer;
    bool IsRunning = true;

    public event EventHandler<ConnectionAttemptEventArgs> ConnectionAttempt;

    // The constructor obtains the state information.
    public PageWatcher(int index, string url, string name, int timer)
    {
        mindex = index;
        murl = url;
        mname = name;
        mtimer = timer;
    }

    public void StartProcess()
    {
        //First run checking
        string lastResult = "Connection Success";

        while (IsRunning)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(mtimer);
            IsRunning = false;

            try
            {
                //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("Process Start", mname);
                DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
                string html = Utility.RequestWebpage(murl, string.Empty, true);
                TimeSpan minisecond = DateTime.Now - start;

                FileManager.WriteActivityLog("time:" + minisecond.Milliseconds.ToString() + ", html length:" + html.Length.ToString(), mname);
                //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("html:" + html, mname);
                //FileManager.WriteActivityLog("Process End", mname);
                lastResult = "Connection Success";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionManager.WriteErrorLog(ex.Message, true, mname);
                lastResult = ex.Message;
            }
            IsRunning = true;
            OnConnectionAttempt(result);
        }
    }

    private void OnConnectionAttempt(string result)
    {
        var handler = ConnectionAttempt;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ConnectionAttemptEventArgs(mindex, result));
        }
    }
}


public class ConnectionAttemptEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public readonly int Index;
    public readonly string Result;

    public ConnectionAttemptEventArgs(int index, string result)
    {
        Index = index;
        Result = result;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
PageWatcher watcher = new PageWatcher(index, url, name, timer);
watcher.ConnectionAttempt += HandleConnectionAttempt;
thSystem[index] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(watcher.StartProcess));
thSystem[index].Start();

...

void HandleConnectionAttempt(object sender, ConnectionAttemptEventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Connection attempt watcher {0}, result {1}", e.Index, e.Result);
}
```

I also renamed your class as `clsCallProcess` is not really a good name. Prefixing it with `cls` to indicate it's a class is rather pointless and `CallProcess` is what it's doing but not what its intent is - which is to watch a connection to a webpage.

Comment: it content alot error to me   

public ConnectionResultEventArgs ,this 1 no put return method

Comment: @user983738: Sorry, that was a typo, it was meant to be the cosntructor. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a "continuation" delegate that takes the result.  The delegate would be called at the end of the method.

```
 clsCallProcess cls = new clsCallProcess(index, url, name, timer);
 thSystem[index] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    () =>
    cls.StartProcess(result => Console.WriteLine (result))));
 // ---------------------------^
 // If you want to do something other than write it to the console, do that here. 
 thSystem[index].Start();
```

Here's the framework of the StartProcess (

```
    public void StartProcess(Action<string> continueWith)
    {
       string result;
       while (IsRunning)
       {
          // do stuff
          result = "success";
       }

       // all done... call continuation delegate.
       continueWith (result);
    }
```

For an alternate, perhaps more friendly way of doing it (if you have .net 4), use: [Continuations with Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx)

Comment: if i by normal call this function like this
cls.StartProcess();
what type should i put to get back?

Comment: mean, cls.StartProcess(result => stringVariable=result)));?